# AUv3 extension is not registered in MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to write a small MacOS app with AUV3 extension.
I followed all the instructions, however, the extension is not registered in the system. I suppose to see it in the list when I execute:

```
pluginkit -mv | grep [MY_EXTENSION_NAME]
```

command, but I see nothing. 
Trying to execute command:

```
pluginkit -a [MY_EXTENSION_PATH]
```

does not give any error or any other output at all.

```
syslog - w
```

also does not shows any error.
There are no compilation errors or even compilation warnings of any kind.

Maybe someone can direct me to some other error log or some tool or verification that can help me. Is there a place where I can read about the registration process and what can go wrong?

I tried:
Xcode 8.2 on El-Capitan
Xcode 9 Beta on High Sierra Beta

Comment: Can you share some of the code you used to register your AUv3 with your system? I verified that I was able to get my AUv3s to appear in pluginkit, so I am guessing something is wrong with your registration process.

Comment: Thanks! It was a long time ago. Eventually there were some info.plist issues.